What is it called when the day and month you were born in are the same as the year?
For example: if some one were to be born on the 20th of January of 2001 20/01/2001(DD/MM/YYYY).

The same thing someone born on either January 21st or December 1st way back in the year 121 was called. :)

Related: What's it called when a date has the same 'day-number' as 'month-number'?

Note that in the US, that date would be 01/20/2001. So there haven't been any dates that exhibit this phenomenon in 800 years (and the US didn't exist then).

I’m voting to close this question because there is no reason to suppose such a word exists.
